# How to disable silverlight in IE webdriver?

Tags: c#, html, silverlight, internet-explorer, webdriver

Here is what I got:
 an upload button, which works through silverlight if it is installed, or through html5 if there is no silverlight. So, I have 2 browsers to test: Chrome and IE. I did common uploading by sending keys to input element and it works good in chrome, but when it comes to IE - it is trying to use silverlight. 
My question is how to disable silverlight or maybe there are some workarounds?
I found out that it is an add-on, so if somebody knows how to disable add-ons or launch iedriver with switches, please, let me know.

Comment: Sending keys to input elements sounds wrong to me. Possibly due to focus issues.

Comment: It is bad idea for Silverlight. But it works good with html5. So the question is how to disable add-ons(Silverlight) in IEdriver to make web portal use html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through many documents about webdriver and it seem to be no way to disable add-ons or  add switches for now. I hope this will save somebody's else time.